# Overide a GET function using python flask

Tags: python, http, flask

I am developing a Python app and using flask. 
I am now writing my GET functions. 
Here's how it should work:

```
GET http://{host_ip}:{port}/GetMessage?applicationId=1
GET http://{host_ip}:{port}/GetMessage?sessionId=aaaa
GET http://{host_ip}:{port}/GetMessage?messageId=bbbb
```

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/GetMessage')
def GetMessage():
    application_id = request.args.get('application_id')
    messages = Message.query.filter_by(user_id=application_id) 
    return render_template('get.html', messages=messages)

@app.route('/GetMessage')
def GetMessage():
    message_id = request.args.get('message_id')
    messages = Message.query.filter_by(message_id=message_id) 
    return render_template('get.html', messages=messages)
```

But it sends me such an error message:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: GetMessage
```

what can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: You can not declare same path twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def GetMessage():
    messages = Message.query.all()
    application_id = request.args.get('application_id')
    if application_id:
        messages.filter_by(user_id=application_id)

    message_id = request.args.get('message_id')
    if message_id:
        messages = message.filter_by(message_id=message_id)  
    return render_template('get.html', messages=messages)
```